# Can I use a lookup value for a range in sum(filter())?

Tags: google-sheets

Here is a formula:

```
=sum(filter(somerange,someotherrange=index(lookups!$E$3:$F$50,match($A34,lookups!$F$3:$F$50,0),1)))
```

So, if the range "someotherrange" contains say apples, pears and oranges, and if I were to lookup apples, pears and oranges in my index match and it returns a single value of "fruit", I would like to sum "somerange" where it is a fruit.

I can hear you yelling "just add a column to your source data table with a lookup for each and base it on that", but the particular sheet I have makes that pretty complicated (just trust me on this).

Continuing this example, is there a way to sum(filter()) on "somerange" where the values in "someotherrange" correspond to a fruit?

Example sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bvt7H2_9cDBqEL8GffDKLUBNE_6uNE-UjlaY9zJulF4/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: An example spreadsheet would help understand what you are trying.

Comment: Also [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en)/[SUMIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en) may be your answer.

Comment: `filter` is NOT an Excel function.

Comment: Here is a sample file illustrating what I'm trying to do: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bvt7H2_9cDBqEL8GffDKLUBNE_6uNE-UjlaY9zJulF4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use formula:

```
=SUM(FILTER(C5:C13,ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A5:A13,A17:B25,2,0))="fruit"))
```

for fruits.